# split a field into subfield in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a noob in scala and hence having a hard time achieving this..

So, I have a data like:

```
foo::bar::baz\tbleh\t1234
```

So, I create an save the data like

```
foo\tbar\tbaz\tbleh\t1234

val data = sc.textFile("filename").map(line=>line.split("\t"))
```

But how do I split the first element in array.

I mean in pyspark this can be done as

```
def format(line):
   chunks = line.split("\t")
   ele_1 = chunks[0].split("::")
   arr = [ele[0], ele[1], ele[2], chunks[1], chunks[2]]
   return "\t".join(arr)
data = sc.textFile("filename").map(lambda x:format(x))
```

What would be the scala equivalent?

Comment: is your data foo::bar::baz\tbleh\t1234 "\t" is also as string or it is tab separator .

Comment: @SandeepPurohit Yes.. sorry.. basically have a tab-delimited file.. the idea is to split the first field (by "::") and then store again as tab delimited file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replaceAll` to replace all the occurrences of `::` with the given string.

Assuming `\t` is the string not tab space

```
scala> """foo::bar::baz\tbleh\t1234""".replaceAll("::", """\\t""")
res4: String = foo\tbar\tbaz\tbleh\t1234
```

Assuming `\t` is tab space

```
scala> "foo::bar::baz\tbleh\t1234".replaceAll("::", "\t")
res7: String = foo  bar  baz    bleh    1234
```

Your code becomes

```
sc.textFile("filename").map(_.replaceAll("::", "\t"))
```

Answer (score 1):

if it is tab separator use the following

```
val data = sc.textFile("filename").map(line=>line.split("\t"))
data.map(line=> line.replaceAll("::","\t")).saveAsTextFile("file path where you want to store")
```